# Format statements from multiple files

Tags: regex, batch-file

I have multiple .sql files in a folder with wrong format.
is there any way (.batch, notepad++ with regular expression) to modify lines as the follow example

```
IF ........ THEN anything ....... END IF;
```

to formatted as below :

```
IF ..... THEN
   anything;
END IF;
```

Also, for the statement

```
OPEN name1; ... FETCH name2 ...; ... CLOSE name3;
```

to be formatted :

```
OPEN name1;
FETCH name2 ...;
CLOSE name3;
```

Could you help me please ?
Thanks in advance for your help

PS : The letters of the statement can be either capital or lower

Comment: Regular Expression perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I would do it using notepad++:

First make sure View->Show Symbol->Show All Characters is selected, this makes it easier to see what is going on and verify your results.

For your first example open the replace window (CTRL-H). In the "Find What" box type "Then_"  (excluding quotes, where underscore = a space). In the "Replace with" box type "Then\r\n\t". Under search mode, select Extended. Click the Replace button. This adds a CR/LF plus a tab to indent the next line.

You should have gone from this:

```
IF ........ THEN anything ....... END IF;
IF ........ THEN anything ....... END IF;
```

To this:

```
IF ........ THEN
    anything ....... END IF;
IF ........ THEN
    anything ....... END IF;
```

Then hit Ctrl-H again. In the "Find What" box type "END IF". In the "Replace With" box type "/r/nEND IF"

Now it should look like this:

```
IF ........ THEN
    anything ....... 
END IF;
IF ........ THEN
    anything ....... 
END IF;
```

Use the last technique to add /r/n before the OPEN, FETCH, and CLOSE commands. It may also be worthwhile to add a newline character to all semi-colons as a starting point (replace ";" with ";/r/n").

Comment: These solutions will affect also the well formatted code.

Comment: If there is well-formatted code alongside the bad (which you didn't mention in your question) I suggest adding it to the example so that we can help you.